# Why does my div start within it's sibling's div in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

First, the page: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/238966491/website/index.html

I'm wondering why the last line of text--"Let us protect you, so you can focus on your business."--is starting as if it's part of the Phone div. I want it to start on its own line, but it seems to think that continuing it from where the Phone div starts is a good idea, despite the `<br>`.

How can I get this div to start on it's own line, so its text is on one line? (It works in Chrome.)

Edit: Here's a CodePen with the problem displayed. A lot isn't working because of the dependencies and stuff, but the problem is still present. See the third section, in the .tagline div. http://codepen.io/bnb/pen/vIBEw

Comment: Please include the relative code we need to see what the problem is, maybe a jsfiddle as well would be nice.

Comment: code snippets and screen caps (optional) and a demo (optional) within your question on required.  Linking to an external site will not get you very many answers

Comment: Using `<br>` tags for positioning is a bad idea anyway. Use margins &/or padding appropriately.

Comment: use a dom inspector. it'll show you the html as the browser loaded/parsed it, which you then compare against the html which you wrote.

Comment: @josephmarikle I updated it. Sorry, I thought giving the actual working file would be enough.  Marc, I've been using the Firefox inspector but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `clear` because before of `.tagline` you have a left floated div. Add this on your CSS:

```
.tagline {
   clear:both;
}
```